# wkhtmltopdf php wrapper's send() not working

Tags: php, angularjs, mime-types, wkhtmltopdf, phalcon

I am trying to convert my html page to pdf using wkhtmltopdf php wrapper with this [library](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf). I have tried to use saveAs() function, that works perfectly fine. But I want to download the generated pdf file on the browser so I used send(filename) function, unfortunately that's not working for me.

Here is my code :

```
public static function generatePDF(){
       $this->setJsonResponse();
       $data = $this->request->getPost();
       $srno = $data["number"];
       $type = $data["type"];
       $html = $data["html"];
       $pdf = new Pdf(array(
              'print-media-type',
              'commandOptions' => array(
                  'useExec' => true, 
                  'procEnv' => array(
                      'LANG' => 'en_US.utf-8',
                  )
       )));
       $pdf->binary = $config->application->wkhtmltopdf_binary;
       $pageOptions = array(
              'disable-smart-shrinking',
       );
       $pdf->addPage($html, $pageOptions);
       $filename = $type . "-" . $srno . '-' . date("Ymd") . '' . date("his") . ".pdf";
       if (!$pdf->send($filename)) {
           $error = $pdf->getError();
           return array('error' => $error);
       }
       return true;
  }
```

I debug the code and I found that there is some problem with MIME type. `send()` requires the MIME Type 'application/pdf' but in my response that is 'application/json'. And that's because of the first line of function `$this->setJsonResponse();`

Here is this function which is in my ControllerBase.php

```
protected function setJsonResponse() {
    $this->json_response = true;

    $this->view->disable();

    $this->response->setContentType('application/json', 'UTF-8');

    // If request AJAX is json type then parse it and update
    // php's POST member.
    $contentType = $this->request->getHeader('CONTENT_TYPE');
    if (strpos(strtolower($contentType), "application/json") !== FALSE) {
        $jsonRawBody = $this->request->getJsonRawBody(true);
        if ($this->request->getRawBody() && !$jsonRawBody) {
            // throw new Exception("Invalid JSON syntax");
        } else {
            $_POST = $jsonRawBody;
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove that function call from `generatePDF`, then I got `$data` empty.
What should I do to make `send()` working and get `$data` not null from the ajax?

P.S.: I am using **AngularJs** on client-side and using http request.

Edit : http request (getJson is a global function I made for project. i.e. just a simple http reqeust or ajax)

```
$rootScope.getJson(controller + '/generatePdf', data, function (r) {
if (r.error) {
    console.log(r.error);
} else if (r.success) {
    var filename = r.success.filename;
    var url = r.success.base + 'temp/' + filename;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
} else {
    console.log('something went wrong');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this function in ControllerBase and calling this in `generatePDF()` :

```
protected function setPdfResponse() {
    $this->json_response = false;
    $this->pdf_response = true;

    $this->view->disable();

    // Important response-headers copied from wkhtmltopdf
    $this->response->setContentType('application/pdf');
    $this->response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public');
    $this->response->setHeader('Expires', '0');
    $this->response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $this->response->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');

    // If request AJAX is json type then parse it and update
    // php's POST member.
    $contentType = $this->request->getHeader('CONTENT_TYPE');
    if (strpos(strtolower($contentType), "application/json") !== FALSE) {
        $jsonRawBody = $this->request->getJsonRawBody(true);
        if ($this->request->getRawBody() && !$jsonRawBody) {
            //throw new Exception("Invalid JSON syntax");
        } else {
            $_POST = $jsonRawBody;
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me and here no need of java-script to build a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can even set headers and output a pdf from an Ajax call. Isn't it the same as trying to make a server side redirect after an Ajax call - Not going to work :)

If I was you, I would save the generated PDF file and return a link to your frontend.

In the `generatePDF()` instead of `send()` use the `saveAs()` method and collect the link. For example `www.website.com/generated-files/pdf-1233.pdf` etc...

After that you only have to return the link to the pdf and handle it in your Angular code. Not an Angular expert, but it should look something like this:

```
.then(function(response) {
    window.location.href = response.pdfLocation;
    ...
});
```

Comment: I tried that but the pdf file which is downloaded is corrupted.

Comment: Can you access the PDF with the link you are returning to your Angular callback? Please, update your question with angular http request code.

Comment: Works fine when i test on localhost. If the file is from different domain Chrome redirects instead of download for security reasons. Maybe just do `window.location.href = url;` and you should be done :)

Also try `console.log(url)`, copy the link and put it in your browser to be 100% sure pdf file is there!